# Finding words after keyword in python

Tags: python, regex, matching, keyword

I want to find words that appear after a keyword (specified and searched by me) and print out the result. I know that i am suppose to use regex to do it, and i tried it out too, like this:

```
import re
s = "hi my name is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more"
m = re.search("^name: (\w+)", s)
print m.groups()
```

The output is just:

```
"is"
```

But I want to get all the words and punctuations that comes after the word "name".

Answer (score 46):

Instead of using regexes you could just (for example) separate your string with [`str.partition(separator)`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) like this:

```
mystring =  "hi my name is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more"
keyword = 'name'
before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = mystring.partition(keyword)
>>> before_keyword
'hi my '
>>> keyword
'name'
>>> after_keyword
' is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more'
```

You have to deal with the needless whitespaces separately, though.

Comment: What if there are multiple 'name' in the same sentence? Your solution wouldn't work then

Comment: It should be `mystring.partition(keyword)` without the quotes around `keyword`

Comment: It will give spurious results if `keyword` appears multiple times in the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :)

Comment: Magnificent! Thank you!

Comment: What about if you wanted to print  out the next word after  'name'? i.e. 'is' and  not  the  entire second part of the sentence. Just the next word?

Answer (score 21):

Your example will not work, but as I understand the idea:

```
regexp = re.compile("name(.*)$")
print regexp.search(s).group(1)
# prints " is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more"
```

This will print all after "name" and till end of the line.

Answer (score 10):

An other alternative...

```
   import re
   m = re.search('(?<=name)(.*)', s)
   print m.groups()
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `"^name: (\w+)"` use:

```
"^name:(.*)"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
s = "hi my name is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more"
m = re.search("^name: (\w+)", s)

print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have used regarding your output:

```
re.search("name (\w+)", s)
```

What you have to use (*match all*):

```
re.search("name (.*)", s)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do

```
s = "hi my name is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more"
s.split('name')
```

This will split your string and return a list like this ['hi my', 'is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more']

depending on what you want to do this may help or not.

Answer (score 2):

This will work out for u : work name\s\w+\s(\w+)

```
>>> s = 'hi my name is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more'
>>> m = re.search('name\s\w+\s(\w+)',s)
>>> m.group(0)
'name is ryan'
>>>> m.group(1)
'ryan'
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using regex, you can

- strip punctuation (consider making everything single case, including search term)
- split your text into individual words
- find index of searched word
- get word from array (`index + 1` for word after, `index - 1` for word before )

Code snippet:

```
import string
s = 'hi my name is ryan, and i am new to python and would like to learn more'
t = 'name'
i = s.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation).split().index(t)
print s.split()[i+1]

>> is
```

---

For multiple occurences, you need to save multiple indices:

```
import string
s = 'hi my NAME is ryan, and i am new to NAME python and would like to learn more'
t = 'NAME'
il = [i for i, x in enumerate(s.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation).split()) if x == t]
print [s.split()[x+1] for x in il]

>> ['is', 'python']
```