# Get authors name and URL for tag from google scholar

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wish to write to a CSV file a list of all authors with their URL to a CSV file who class themselves as a specific tag on Google Scholar. For example, if we were to take ['security'](http://scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=pl&mauthors=label:security) I would want this output:

```
author          url
Howon Kim       https://scholar.google.pl/citations?user=YUoJP-oAAAAJ&hl=pl
Adrian Perrig   https://scholar.google.pl/citations?user=n-Oret4AAAAJ&hl=pl
...             ...
```

I have written this code which prints each author's name

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=pl&mauthors=label:security"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
mydivs = soup.findAll("h3", { "class" : "gsc_1usr_name"})
outputFile = open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
for each in mydivs:
    for anchor in each.find_all('a'):
        print (anchor.text)
```

However, this only does it for the first page. Instead, I would like to go through every page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not writing the code for you.. but I'll give you an outline for how you can.

Look at the bottom of the page. See the next button? Search for it the containing div has an `id` of `gsc_authors_bottom_pag` which should be easy to find. I'd do this with selenium, find the next button (right) and click it. Wait for the page to load, scrape repeat. Handle edge cases (out of pages, etc).

If the `after_author=*` bit didn't change in the url you could just increment the `url` start.. but unless you want to try to crack that code (unlikely) then just click the next button.

Answer (score 1):

This page use `<button>` instead of `<a>` for link to next/previous page.

Button to next page has `aria-label="Następna"`.

There are two buttons to next page but you can use any of them.

Button has `JavaScript` code to redirect to new page

```
 window.location=url_to_next_page
```

but it is simple text so you can use slicing to get only url

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=pl&mauthors=label:security"

while True:    
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    # ... do something on page ...

    # find buttons to next page
    buttons = soup.findAll("button", {"aria-label": "Następna"})

    # exit if no buttons
    if not buttons:
        break

    on_click = buttons[0].get('onclick')

    print('javascript:', on_click)

    #add `domain` and remove `window.location='` and `'` at the end
    url = 'http://scholar.google.pl' + on_click[17:-1]
    # converting some codes to chars 
    url = url.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')

    print('url:', url)
```

---

BTW: if you speak Polish then you can visit on Facebook: [Python Poland](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpl/) or [Python: pierwsze kroki](https://www.facebook.com/groups/pythonpierwszekroki/)

Comment: How can I loop through all of the pages?

Comment: simple use `while True` loop.

Comment: I add `url.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')` because page uses unicode numbers instead of chars.

Answer (score 0):

Since [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41325165/15164646) is already answered on how to loop through all pages, this is a complementary answer to his answer. The script below scrapes much more than your question asks and scrapes to a `.csv` file.

Code and [example in online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Scholar-pythonserpapi#bs4_results/get_profiles.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, os, csv

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}


def get_profiles_to_csv():
    html = requests.get('http://scholar.google.pl/citations?view_op=search_authors&hl=pl&mauthors=label:security', headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    # creating CSV File
    with open('awesome_file.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
      # defining column names
      fieldnames = ['Author', 'URL']
      # defining .csv writer
      # https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter
      writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
      # writing (creating) columns
      writer.writeheader()

      # collecting scraped data
      author_data = []

      # Selecting container where all data located 
      for result in soup.select('.gs_ai_chpr'):
        name = result.select_one('.gs_ai_name a').text
        link = result.select_one('.gs_ai_name a')['href']

        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633693/15164646
        # id = link
        # id_identifer = 'user='
        # before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = id.partition(id_identifer)
        # author_id = after_keyword
        # affiliations = result.select_one('.gs_ai_aff').text
        # email = result.select_one('.gs_ai_eml').text
        # try:
        #   interests = result.select_one('.gs_ai_one_int').text
        # except:
        #   interests = None
        
        # "Cited by 107390" = getting text string -> splitting by a space -> ['Cited', 'by', '21180'] and taking [2] index which is the number.
        # cited_by = result.select_one('.gs_ai_cby').text.split(' ')[2]

        # because we have a csv.DictWriter() we converting to the required format
        # dict() keys should be exactly the same as fieldnames, otherwise it will throw an error
        author_data.append({
          'Author': name,
          'URL': f'https://scholar.google.com{link}',
        })
      
      # iterating over celebrity data list() that became dict() and writing it to the .csv
      for data in author_data:
        writer.writerow(data)
        
        # print(f'{name}\nhttps://scholar.google.com{link}\n{author_id}\n{affiliations}\n{email}\n{interests}\n{cited_by}\n')

# output from created csv:
'''
Author,URL
Johnson Thomas,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=eKLr0EgAAAAJ
Martin Abadi,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=vWTI60AAAAAJ
Adrian Perrig,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=n-Oret4AAAAJ
Vern Paxson,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=HvwPRJ0AAAAJ
Frans Kaashoek,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=YCoLskoAAAAJ
Mihir Bellare,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=2pW1g5IAAAAJ
Matei Zaharia,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=I1EvjZsAAAAJ
John A. Clark,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=xu3n6owAAAAJ
Helen J. Wang,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=qhu-DxwAAAAJ
Zhu Han,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=pl&user=ty7wIXoAAAAJ
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Scholar Profiles API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-profiles-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import csv, os


def get_profiles_to_csv():
    with open('awesome_serpapi_file_pagination.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['Author', 'URL']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        params = {
            "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
            "engine": "google_scholar_profiles",
            "mauthors": "label:security"
        }

        search = GoogleSearch(params)

        while True:
            results = search.get_dict()
            try:
              for result in results['profiles']:
                  name = result['name']
                  link = result['link']

                  writer.writerow({'Author': name, 'URL': link})
            except:
              print('Done')
              break

            if (not 'pagination' in results) and (not 'next' in results['pagination']):
                break

            search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results["pagination"]["next"]).query)))


get_profiles_to_csv()

# part of the output from created csv:
'''
Author,URL
Johnson Thomas,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=eKLr0EgAAAAJ
Martin Abadi,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=vWTI60AAAAAJ
Adrian Perrig,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=n-Oret4AAAAJ
Vern Paxson,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=HvwPRJ0AAAAJ
Frans Kaashoek,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=YCoLskoAAAAJ
Mihir Bellare,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=2pW1g5IAAAAJ
Matei Zaharia,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=I1EvjZsAAAAJ
John A. Clark,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=xu3n6owAAAAJ
Helen J. Wang,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=qhu-DxwAAAAJ
Zhu Han,https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=ty7wIXoAAAAJ
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.