# Grabbing words surrounding keywords when keywords show up multiple times in string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Intro: I am trying to extract surrounding words next to a key word of choice. I've learned how to do this using re.compile. Other threads address this issue, e.g.: [Finding words after keyword in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633678/finding-words-after-keyword-in-python)

Problem: My issues is that what if `keyword` appears more than one time in a string. e.g., my keyword is "pie" and my string (`s1`) is: "i like to eat blueberry pie it is delicious but i also like to eat apple pie it is cool."

How do I extract "blueberry", "it", "apple" and "it"? My current method only extracts "blueberry" and "it."

Current method:

```
re.compile(r'((?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){1})+pie\s+((?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){1})').findall(s1)
```

Thanks let me know if you need clarification!

Comment: Note: I would like to use regex.

Comment: Resolved: I need to use re.findall instead of re.compile