# Web Scraping Google Scholar Author profiles

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, google-scholar

I have used scholarly package and parsed the author names generated in the 3 question its method search by author name to get the author profiles including all the citation information of all the professors. I was able to load the data into a final dataframe with NA values for those who do not have a google scholar profile.
However, there is an issue approx. 8 authors citation information is not matching the information on google scholar website, it is because the scholarly package is retrieving the citation information of other authors with the same name. I believe I can fix it by using search_author_id function but the question is how do we get the author_ids of all the professors in the first place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Yash

Answer (score 1):

This solution possibly will not be suitable for the `scholarly` package. `beautifulsoup` will be used instead.

Author `id's` is located under the tag name inside the `<a>` tag `href` attribute. Here's how we can grab their id's:

```py
# assumes that request and soup are already sent and made

link = soup.select_one('.gs_ai_name a')['href']

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633693/15164646
_id = link

# looking for the text that contains "user=" to split it to 3 parts.
id_identifer = 'user='

# splitting text to 3 parts
before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = _id.partition(id_identifer)

# after_keyword means that everything AFTER "user=" will be scraped, which is ID.
author_id = after_keyword

# RlANTZEAAAAJ
```

---

Code that goes a "bit" out of your question scope ([full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Scholar-pythonserpapi#main.py) under bs4 folder -> `get_profiles.py`):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, os

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

proxies = {
  'http': os.getenv('HTTP_PROXY')
}

html = requests.get('https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_org&hl=en&org=9834965952280547731', headers=headers, proxies=proxies).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.gs_ai_chpr'):
  name = result.select_one('.gs_ai_name a').text
  link = result.select_one('.gs_ai_name a')['href']

  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633693/15164646
  _id = link
  id_identifer = 'user='
  before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = _id.partition(id_identifer)
  author_id = after_keyword
  affiliations = result.select_one('.gs_ai_aff').text
  email = result.select_one('.gs_ai_eml').text

  try:
    interests = result.select_one('.gs_ai_one_int').text
  except:
    interests = None

  cited_by = result.select_one('.gs_ai_cby').text.split(' ')[2]
  
  print(f'{name}\nhttps://scholar.google.com{link}\n{author_id}\n{affiliations}\n{email}\n{interests}\n{cited_by}\n')
```

Output:

```
Jeong-Won Lee
https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=D41VK7AAAAAJ
D41VK7AAAAAJ
Samsung Medical Center
Verified email at samsung.com
Gynecologic oncology
107516
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing with [Google Scholar Profiles API](https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-profiles-api) from SerpApi, but without thinking about how to solve the CAPTCHA, find proxies, and maintain the parser over time.

It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),      # your serpapi API key
    "engine": "google_scholar_profiles",  # search engine
    "mauthors": "samsung"                 # search query
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)             # where data extraction happens
results = search.get_dict()               # JSON -> Python dictionary

for result in results.get('profiles'):
    name = result.get('name')
    email = result.get('email')
    author_id = result.get('author_id')
    affiliation = result.get('affiliations')
    cited_by = result.get('cited_by')
    interests = result['interests'][0]['title']
    interests_link = result['interests'][0]['link']

print(f'{name}\n{email}\n{author_id}\n{affiliation}\n{cited_by}\n{interests}\n{interests_link}\n')
```

Part of the output:

```
Jeong-Won Lee
Verified email at samsung.com
D41VK7AAAAAJ
Samsung Medical Center
107516
Gynecologic oncology
https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=search_authors&mauthors=label:gynecologic_oncology
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Comment: How to scrap the data from the fellowing pages?

Comment: @Mohamed-IslemHachaichi the ones from the output?

Comment: let's say that I want to srap GS profiles that belong to a given university (assuming that there is 120 profiles), but google scholar displays only 10 profiles per page, how to jump to the next page?

Comment: @Mohamed-IslemHachaichi Got it! I wrote a dedicated [scrape Google Scholar Profiles from a certain University in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-scholar-profiles-from-a-certain-university-in-python/#full_code) blog post about it, using a custom solution via [`parsel`](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/) and SerpApi solution. Let me know if it's what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, thanks for the suggestion. But I still can't manage to delete the "label" from the params. Can you try to retrive data from "EM Normandie"? I can't use your code! please can you help asap. Many thanks.

Comment: @Mohamed-IslemHachaichi you have to delete `label` function argument to make it work. I've [created a Github gist with `parsel` solution that shows an output](https://gist.github.com/dimitryzub/eb00fe06d32e81178878fcd4f1c35e16), and it's working great both locally and on replit, with the query you provided. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, it does work now. Do you have any idea on how to retrieve data from ResearchGate?

Comment: @Mohamed-IslemHachaichi awesome! What exactly are you looking to parse from researchgate? Can you share the link?

Comment: the link: (https://www.researchgate.net/institution/EM-Normandie-Business-School/members), but then I want to go to each profile and scrabe: Research Interest, Citations, and h-index.

Comment: @Mohamed-IslemHachaichi Thank you. For now, I don't have any suggestions for you. I'll make a blog post about scraping all institution members and their profiles (whole page) very soon. What are your thoughts on having a ResearchGate API on SerpApi?

Comment: Hey Dmitriy, let's say I want to collect the article titles of each author? how to do so, I've already consulted your blog but the wode does not work! it yields nothing...

Comment: Hey @Mohamed-IslemHachaichi, the code from Scrape Google Scholar Profiles from a certain University blog post works. If you want to parse titles from author pages, this code will not work, this is correct behavior as there are other selectors and elements. [Check out this gist to scrape all publications from the authors' page](https://github.com/dimitryzub/stackoverflow-answers-archive/blob/main/answers/Dmitriy/twitter_answers/google/google_scholar/google_scholar_authors/python/google-scholar-extract-all-author-publications.py).

Comment: Hey @Dmitriy Zub, can we please take the year of the publication of the article? with the article titles? I collected the article titles, but I don't find a way to add the year of the title (article)?

Comment: Hey @MohamedHachaichi, I've [added year extraction to the script](https://github.com/dimitryzub/stackoverflow-answers-archive/blob/main/answers/Dmitriy/twitter_answers/google/google_scholar/google_scholar_authors/python/google-scholar-extract-all-author-publications.py) and a SerpApi solution. If you don't have a proxies/captcha solver, an API solution is the way to go since it solves this problem. At some point, you will run into a problem where requests are blocked.